# JMeter throws "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)"when trying to configure master - slave on Amazon EC2 cluster

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jmeter, remote-server

I have reserved a number of **Linux based EC2** machines(running OS : **Centos 7**) and with the exact same versions of **JMeter 4.0** and Java installed. 
No active firewalls, all the devices are connected within the same subnet and I can easily ping between them.
The problem is that I when I try to configure a mater machine and connect it to one of my slaves I keep receiving this exception

`Connection refused to host: xx.yy.zz.4; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Failed to configure xx.yy.zz.4
Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[xx.yy.zz.4]`

I have made my slave(ip: xx.yy.zz.4) setup as follows:
`server_port = 24000 , server.rmi.localport=26000 , server.rmi.ssl.disable=true`, No Remote Hosts and I usually launch the server using this shell command:

```
./jmeter-server -n -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.yy.zz.4
```

And for the master which is also another EC2 instance(ip: xx.yy.zz.21) I made these configurations:

```
remote_hosts=xx.yy.zz.4:24000 , client.rmi.localport=25000, server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

And I use this shell command to start my JMeter's test plan
 `./jmeter -n -Rxx.yy.zz.4 -t /home/centos/jmeter/scripts/demo.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.yy.zz.21`

Any idea on what might cause these error?

Comment: You said there's no active firewall, but what about the Security Group. Is it configured to accept incoming requests from the specified port (24000, 25000...etc.) ? Also, which IP are you using ? I don't know your VPC configuration, but for internal communication you have to use the private IP.

Comment: Yes my Sec group is configured to accept inbound traffic from these ports, and all the IPs that I am using are private.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal configuration:

- slave:

  ```
  ./jmeter-server -Dserver_port=24000
  ```
- master:

  ```
  ./jmeter -n -R xx.yy.zz.4:24000 -t test.jmx
  ```

More information:

- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be always using the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity